# BackgroundAudioPlayer can't play link like "llnwd.net"

Tags: windows-phone, background-audio

I access this link

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/112591184/streams?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=ff19f157
```

and can get mp3 link like:

```
https://soundcloud.hs.llnwd.net/dM7lqg9JGehn.128.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1393349497&Signature=cNBZPQMGGmCjc1CvyXELy1edfVk%3D&e=1393349497&h=9807761d2092a0b8b13b06ebdba24a12
```

I can use this mp3 link for both playing and downloading
But when I use this link to play in BackgroundAudioPlayer of Windows Phone
It can't play, I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: this is link of the code, it is in class AudioPlayer of AudioPlaybackAgent project
http://hightechnology.mobi/data/AudioPlayer.txt

Comment: Note: replace "\u0026" by "&" for mp3 link

Comment: I am having the same issue but with Blackberry Cascades! Did you ever find a solution?